# Is there a way to separate strings in a list that have commas in them from a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matrix

trying to take a csv file with undefined number of rows and columns and trying to turn it into a list of lists while slicing certain entries and removing some of the content.

ie:
CSV contents:

```
num Name    alt : bar
1   foo 1   A : bar,B : bar
2   foo 2   C : bar,D : bar
```

end goal:

```
[['foo 1','A','B'],['foo 2','C','D']
```

In python, I've used pandas to read the csv and have already tried converting the file using .tolist() but am unsure of how the slicing should work repeatedly

```py
import pandas as pd

matrix = pd.read_csv('matrix.csv',index_col = 0)
matrix = matrix.values.tolist()
matrix = [matrix(i) for i in matrix[1].split(',')]
```

the code above gets me to:
`matrix = [['foo 1', 'A : bar,B : bar'], ['foo 2', 'C : bar,D : bar']]` 
before the last line where the split function is giving me trouble. I'm also unsure of how to get rid of the `: bar` at the end of each of the sliced strings once they are sliced

Comment: All you want to do is to remove the `: bar`?

Comment: right now the ```A : bar , B : bar``` is a single string and I need to slice the string and the remove the bar from both. ideally it is done recursively for all the items in column ```alt : bar```

Comment: In your CSV file, are your columns tab separated?

Comment: no, but the CSV file comes from a different program and I am trying to not change anything in the CSV file so I can eventually import it back in the same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic approach (the only one which comes to my mind) is to iterate over each row and perform splitting operations on the strings to extract the data you need.

```
ll = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    r = [row["num Name"]]
    el = [x.split(':')[0].strip() for x in row["alt : bar"].split(',')]
    r.extend(el)
    ll.append(r)
```

`ll` is:

```
[['foo 1', 'A', 'B'], ['foo 2', 'C', 'D']]
```